# Spring Integration: Splitter to service activator to http outbound gateway

Tags: xml, spring, spring-integration

I am facing the problem of multi-threading where the whole process flow should run within 30seconds

1st source: general list of 200 jobs
2nd source: splitter to call 2nd source individually by taking from source 1 job id

After splitting, I will pass it to a **queue** to call the **service activator** where it will then call the **http outbound gateway**. However, since it is currently single thread it will face a problem where within 30 seconds it is unable to finish all the 200 jobs

```xml
<int:splitter input-channel="AdapterCollectTransformJobChannel" output-channel="AdapterCollectTransformJobChannelSplit" ref="processesSplitter" />

<int:channel id="AdapterCollectTransformJobChannelSplit">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="invokeJobGeneralChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>


<int:service-activator input-channel="invokeJobGeneralChannel" ref="AD001JobGeneralServiceActivator">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="0" />
</int:service-activator>

<int:gateway default-request-channel="AdapterCollectRequestChannel"
                 service-interface="adapter.ad001.AD001CollectGateway">
        <int:method name="invoke" payload-expression="#args[0]" reply-timeout="5000">
            <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
            <int:header name="HttpMethod" value="GET" />
            <int:header expression="#args[1]" name="HttpUri" />
            <int:header expression="#args[2]" name="AccountId" />
            <int:header expression="#args[3]" name="MachineId" />
            <int:header expression="#args[4]" name="ApiName" />
        </int:method>
   </int:gateway>
```

Log:
[Thread log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQgAV.png)

Update 2: 
Log: [enter link description here](https://file.io/2HLVIS)
Xml: [enter link description here](https://file.io/hES8MR)
I realize that the request will get override from the log attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no any parallelism with your service-activator for the `invokeJobGeneralChannel`. Just because the `PollingConsumer` polls as much messages from the queue within a single call as there is in the queue. Therefore the call of the service happens in a single thread.

To make it really multi-threaded you need to configure an `ExecutorChannel` instead of `QueueChannel` after splitter.

On the other hand that isn't clear why do your treat `http outbound gateway` as a single-threaded? Its' definitely not true because we are fully OK to call REST in parallel.
Please, share more evidence why do you think it is a single-threaded.

Comment: Hi, I have screenshot the log where it shows that when the service activator is being called its running on different thread but when it calls the http request it's running on single thread.

Comment: Ok! Show, please, more configuration, especially for the HTTP Outbound Gateway and its channel! The current piece of code doesn’t reflect the logs

Comment: Btw, I’ve explained you in my answer how it gets a single-threaded in case of queue channel